# PhoneGap AJAX URL issue with one controller in Codeigniter but second one works fine

Tags: php, codeigniter, phonegap

1. I am creating a PhoneGap app for my website.
2. The server is live and I am using 2 controllers and 2 models.
3. There is no issue with one controller but when I try to access the second controller with AJAX the URL is mixed with a proxy URL which starts  http://192.168.1.9:3000/proxy/https%3A%2F%2Fmywebsite.com%2Fcontroller2%2Fmethodname.

The only one difference between the two ontrollers were the second one doesn't have include **'connection.php'**. I updated it but still no improvement. I tried in localhost it works fine.
I also try to use first controller(live server) in the same ajax call and it's working.

I almost spend a day to find a solution but nothing found.
Thanks advance.

Contoller 1 heading

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
include 'connection.php';
```

Contoller 2 heading

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
include 'connection.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble.
I have checked the URL myself and found that the page/URL does not exist.